# Laravel Generate url based on username

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm new to  Laravel and i'm working on social application and i want the generated routes be something  like this :

```
-www.app.com/username

-www.app.com/username/boards

-www.app.com/username/boards/ID 

-www.app.com/username/follower .. etc
```

Any help with that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do things like this with Laravel's router:

```
Route::get('{username}/boards', 'BoardsController@show')
   ->where('username', '[A-Za-z]+');
```

And then you just need a controller:

```
class BoardsController extends Controller {

    public function show($username)
    {
        return "showing boards for $username";
    }

}
```